# laravel orm : update result set of a ->get() query at once

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

imagen this scenario , 
we want to show notifications to admin about new orders  ,after clicking to see new orders

```
$neworders = Orders::where('admin_seen' , 0 )->paginate(20);
```

now we want to flag these orders as seen

is there anyway to flag all of thgem at once without having to loop trough them ? like

```
$newsorders->all()->update(['admin_seen' => 1] );
```

Comment: It does not work?

Comment: @Buglinjo , Alexey Mezenin answer works tough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `all()` or `update()` with paginated results, for example if you'll try to use `update()`, you'll get `BadMethodCallException with message 'Method update does not exist` exception.

So do this:

```
$neworders = Orders::where('admin_seen', 0)->paginate(20);
Orders::whereIn('id', $neworders->pluck('id'))->update(['admin_seen' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your query without `all()`:

```
$newsorders->update(['admin_seen' => 1]);
```